# Database threads per request using Ecto

Tags: json, architecture, elixir, psql, ecto

A typical Elixir web application will usually have a postgresql  backend, with `Ecto` queries coupled with the API logic.

However since `cowboy` creates a child `GenServer` process (containing the app logic) per request, will this have the effect of producing **n** psql threads for **n** concurrent requests, even with the pooling `cowboy`/`poolboy` provides?

Then, moving to a scenario where multiple instances of the application exists (for example a docker container cluster) will this not add an extra factor to the total number of existing database threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cowboy does create a new Erlang process for each request but executing an Ecto query from that process will *not* result in a new Database connection. Ecto keeps a pool of connections to the database (using db_connection/poolboy). The size of this pool is set using the `pool_size` option in the configuration of the Repo. When you initiate a query, a connection from this pool is borrowed and used to execute the query. The connection is returned to the pool after the execution is complete. Ecto will never create a new connection for each query. If a connection is not available in the pool, it'll wait for one to be available or eventually time out if no connection is checked in in the configured timeout (defaults to 30 seconds).

Comment: Thank you - calculating to max number of app db threads across **n** app instances should then just be **n** * `pool_size`

Comment: Yes, that's right. Each instance of the app will open `pool_size` connections.

Comment: Isn't this a problem? I mean, if the number of instances grows uncontrollably then n*pool_size threads could just kill the DB under heavy load, what you do in that case in the Elixir world?

Comment: I understand that if you control the connection pool_size cluster-wise with a value proportional to what the DB server can handle, it could solve the issues like this. Is there something like this in Ecto?

Comment: Note that `:pool_timeout` was removed and has been replaced with a smarter queueing: https://hexdocs.pm/db_connection/DBConnection.html#start_link/2-queue-config